# eager loading with dbcontext and projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

We are converting our project from ObjectContext to dbContext.
Our current problem is with the difference in how eager loading is handled.

Example context

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
public class Email
{
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
    public string Content{ get; set; }
}
```

we have many pieces of code throughout the enterprise that expect the emails to be loaded and therefore call `person.Emails.First()` without thinking about it.
So we need to make sure that `Emails` are eagerly loaded.

Sometimes we can just us `Include`

However, when we use projections in our data layer we are running into problems. i.e.

```
return context.Persons.Select(p=> new Top5VM {
    Person = p,
    TopPosts = p.Posts.Take(5)
};
```

We have a lot of code that relies on `Top5VM` and expects `Person.Emails` to be loaded.

No mater what we've tried we can not figure out where to put the `Include` (or `Load`) function call where it will actually make a difference .

With the ObjectContext we would just have a dummy property on the `Top5VM` called `Emails`. Once that was loaded, the ObjectContext had references to all of those `Entities` an therefore never needed to go back to the server even when we accessed them through the person object. But that no longer works with the DbContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I need to set `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` any time I want to use projection to accomplish eager loading. Unless of course I want to access the loaded entities directly from the projection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by always using your own `DbContext` in between:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Then use this everywhere instead of a `DbContext`.

Alternately, if you have control of all the POCOs, you could just remove the `virtual` keyword from the related collections ... the `virtual` keyword is the magic hookup Microsoft uses for lazy loading.

**EDIT**

I also tend to do this as an extension method:

```
static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static DbContext AsEagerLoadingContext(this IDbContext context)
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        //context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        return context;
    }
}
```

Used as so, allowing lazy loading to be used or not as needed:

```
using (var context = new DbContext().AsEagerLoadingContext())
    context.Stuff.Select(s => s.AllTheThings);
```

Comment: Thank you. Most of the time I do want Lazy Loading. But I would like the ability to Eager Load when necessary (only the properties that I need) . The projection allows for that as long as I temporarily turn off the LazyLoading.

Comment: Since answering, I got a chance to look at how I do it in code at work - that looks something like this (see edit).